# Why does gcc support a boolean type with std=gnu89?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

Why does gcc support a boolean type with std=gnu89?
At first, I think gcc doesn't support this.

To test this, I wrote one c file like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    bool x;
    printf("size of bool:%lu\n",sizeof(x));
    return 0;
}
```

And I ran gcc:

```
$ gcc -std=gnu89 my_ex.c
```

But it succeeded.

Can we use a boolean type even if with `-std=gnu89`?
If so, what is the reason?

Comment: A gnu extension obviously

Comment: Because gnu89 means "add all manner of non-standard stuff, while at the same time ignoring some parts of the standard".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online C reference [states that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean):

> The C programming language, as of C99, **supports Boolean arithmetic** with the built-in type _Bool (see _Bool). When the header  is included, **the Boolean type is also accessible as bool**.

Further, from this GNU [reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Standards.html),

> **You may also select an extended version of the C language explicitly with -std=gnu89** (for C89 with GNU extensions) or -std=gnu99 (for C99 with GNU extensions). The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu89; this will change to -std=gnu99 in some future release when the C99 support is complete. **Some features that are part of the C99 standard are accepted as extensions in C89 mode**.
>
> The ISO C standard defines (in clause 4) two classes of conforming implementation. A conforming hosted implementation supports the whole standard including all the library facilities; a conforming freestanding implementation is only required to provide certain library facilities: those in , , , and ; since AMD1, also those in ; and in C99, also those in  and .

So you can see from the highlighted portions above, some features that are part of the C99 standard are accepted as extensions in C89 mode. **And `bool` is one of those features**.

Comment: Note that the 'some future release' is a now-ancient release — GCC 5.0.0 upgraded to make `-std=gnu11` the default (there was no version that made `-std=gnu99` the default).  The current version of GCC is 8.2.0; 5.0.0 is no longer maintained by the GCC team (nor are versions 4.x, nor indeed 6.x).

Comment: GCC 8.2 also has upgraded to C17.

Comment: @JensGustedt: According to the [GCC 8.2 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Standards.html#C-Language), the default is still C11: _The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is `-std=gnu11`._  It also notes: _A version with corrections integrated is known as C17 and is supported with `-std=c17` or `-std=iso9899:2017`; the corrections are also applied with `-std=c11`, and the only difference between the options is the value of `__STDC_VERSION__`._  'Tis a pity that the standard is actually ISO/IEC 9899:2018.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, my gcc simply gave me `201710` for `__STDC_VERSION__`. And yes, ISO is slow and unpredictable so they happen to publish the standard 6 month after the committee voted it. This has a probability of `0.5` to fall in another year than the year of the macro. And no, this is not the only difference, there are corrections that force certain interpretations that had been ambiguous before. You might have  a look at https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/04/17/c17/

Comment: @JensGustedt: Your blog was already on my 'to do' list.  The description I quoted says the corrections (from C17) are applied in both C11 and C17 mode.  It may be that the other quote is incorrect — a documentation error.  Empirical testing says that indeed, the default `__STDC_VERSION__` with 8.2.0 is `201710L`, confirming that there is a bug(let) in the GCC 8.2.0 documentation.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Incidentally, this is a known, unfixed bug in GCC documentation: [GCC bug 85917](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85917).